# How do I make the fill padding in std::format dynamic?

Tags: rust

To create a format output and pad your output with `n` you can do something like this in rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let title = " Title ";
    println!("┌{:─^11}┐", title);
}
```

That will print:

```
┌── Title ──┐
```

So the str is padded (centered via `^`) on both sides with `-` within the space of 11 characters.

How can I make this width dynamic though? Via a variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So turns out that's a built-in functionality. [`std::format`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#width) comes with a `width` option indicated with a postfix `$`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let title = " Title ";
    println!("┌{:─^width$}┐", title, width = 11);
}
```

This will print:

```
┌── Title ──┐
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5666cd7f274d436e2216e7ecd0320072

Comment: It's not actually a "width option", it's that for some fields (width and precision currently being the only ones) the format minilanguage accepts parameters and they're postfixed by `$`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb85db082d3cce3fc62a5ae3d8d15577.

Comment: Yeah right. Part of the challenge to figure this out was to find the words to describe it